# Develop webservices in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, upload

I want to put my data on server for that I want to use webservice.Can anybody give details for that please.?How can develop webservice in asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using WCF, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784 and follow the tutorials.